# 18.04 sudo prime-select intel gives ERROR the installed packages do not support PRIME

Tags: dell, 18.04, intel, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

18.04 Dell XPS 15

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

gives ERROR the installed packages do not support PRIME

Where can I find out more about how to proceed?

Comment: is nvidia-prime installed?

Comment: yes. of course. can't get to gives ERROR the installed packages do not support PRIME without it

Comment: Did blacklisting nouveau and using bbswitch as described in my answer work?

Comment: Anything in dmesg?

Comment: yes, but please be more specific. dmesg is gigantic. what messages are we interested in, and how do i run the command to get just those?

Comment: try dmesg | grep nvidia to look for nvidia related issues, you may also want to look for bbswitch.

Comment: nothing for either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

Also, you may need to do as [described here](https://medium.com/@agathver/nvidia-gpu-optimus-prime-and-ubuntu-18-04-woes-f52e7f850f3d):

```
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-fallback.service
```

Add

```
nouveau.blacklist=1
```

in /etc/default/grub in the line GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT

```
sudo update-grub
```

Install [bbswitch-dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/bbswitch-dkms) (`sudo apt install bbswitch-dkms`), and add `bbswitch` to `/etc/modules`.

Comment: Did all these steps, same error message.

Comment: I've made prime-select work. I have no idea how.

Now, I've got the sad 18.04 problem that switching to intel driver leaves the nvidia card on.

sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch 
cat: /proc/acpi/bbswitch: No such file or directory

This is not what I expected!

Comment: Ran sudo modprobe bbswitch, and now cat returns ON.

Running sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch just hangs indeterminately in terminal

Searching for something to kill the card with bbswitch

Comment: FOUND IT!

tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF

I was formatting my command wrong. 

Now I'm at 11.1W, exactly as expected. Thanks for your advice HypnoToad!

Comment: @TomMercer Glad it's working for you now, if this answer was enough to get it done, mark it as such, and if not, please write your own solution and mark it as answered so that others could benefit from it. (btw, do you have to restart when switching, or is login\logout enough, as it is in previous Ubuntu version?)

Comment: i don't switch. there's nothing to do with nvidia card in linux. i would want to be able to run certain apps like games and tensorflow on the nvidia card, but it's too much hassle. i just wanted to waste 10W instead of 25W for ~12 hours of battery life instead of ~4.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with my gtx 1050 on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Install the nvidia driver (in my case `nvidia-driver-390`)

Open `/etc/default/grub` and removed all options in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

Run sudo update-grub and then restart.

Now you can run `sudo prime-select intel` with no errors.
Also you can use nvidia settings GUI to define which gpu to use under PRIME Profiles

Comment: I'm re-doing this with 18.10 right now. The issue is with 18.04 on (iirc) prime-select intel does NOT power down the nvidia card! You have to go through the further steps I listed.