# After upgrading Kubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 get black screen on login

Tags: 18.04, xorg

After upgrading Kubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 the system seemed to work ok except for problems with multiple monitors.

But after a reboot X started crashing on start up (that's another problem). I removed the Nvidia card, and now I can get to the login screen. But after logging in the screen goes blank with just the mouse cursor visible.

I can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to a tty. I've tried `xrandr` from there but can't connect to the X display.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to stop gdm from a tty and tried starting out using startx, where I got a window containing "Could not sync environment to dbus." and OK button. On clicking Ok the X session terminates. In ~/.X's I see "dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1000/bus: Connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

The answer seemed to be to remove and purge the nvidia drivers.

However I now have the nvidia card working after following advice in 
[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041071/18-04-sudo-prime-select-intel-gives-error-the-installed-packages-do-not-support)

Unfortunately I'm still limited the one graphics card with DVI and VGA, whereas in 16.04 I was successfully running 3 monitors via two cards.